# ASP.NET Membership DataTables relationships

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-membership, entity-relationship

I used the ASP.NET membership and have some confusions in its data table. Why the database has aspnet_Membership and aspnet_User table separate because both contains the info of user and apparently no need to make different tables. beside this find PasswordSalt confusing. Kindly someone explain or share a link for details of relationships of tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to why they do what they do I'm not really sure on that one. but I can give a little context to the relationships between the two.

aspnet_users contains the user information for the account.
aspnet_membership contains the login info and ties to a user

In all reality could these be one table, sure, but they do separate two key pieces of information the user and the password.  Also just like everything else the ASP.NET system is modular in the way that you can enable/disable different features and keeping the tables separate helps with that.

The PasswordSalt is used when encrypting/hashing the password to add additional randomness to the passwords so that even with the same password the values wouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the diagram: http://superpatrick.wordpress.com/2007/11/21/aspnet-membership-schema/

Membership is separate from user because you can turn on profile, authorization, web parts and still turn *off* membership. For example, if you are using windows authentication (i.e. Active Directory) as your membership store, then the membership table is left unused and the user table needs only a few columns to help id the windows user that owns things in the profile, or web parts table.